# "Description" for compactitem on the same page

Tags: lists, page-breaking, paralist

Sometimes a have a construct like:

```
Some examples:
\begin{compactitem}
\item first
\item second
\item third
\end{compactitem}
```

With the `samepage` environment, I can enforce to put the entire list on one page, but I would like to have at least one of the items on the same page than "Some examples:". Is there a way to avoid a pagebreak there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, which is working for me:

```
\begin{samepage}
Some examples:
\begin{compactitem}
\item first
\end{compactitem}
\end{samepage}
\begin{compactitem}
\item second
\item third
\end{compactitem}
```